# Use entry to find dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, tkinter

I am trying to use the `entry.get()` method to use the input to search for a dictionary.
I have few dictionaries in a file and the name of the dictionary is the title of a book and I am trying to make a label with the year but it wont use it because it is a string.
Here is the GUI:

```
from Tkinter import *
from Fonction import *  #Fonction is where my functions are stored
from alexandria import * #alexandria is where my dicts are

root2 = Tk()
root2.title("Find")

Title = Label(root2, text = 'Book Title',  font = ('arial',20,'bold'))
Title.grid (row = 0, column = 0)
titlein = Entry(root2)
titlein.grid (row = 0, column = 1)
Findbutt = Button (root2, text = 'Find', font = ('arial',20,'bold'), command = 
lambda : search(titlein.get())) #titlein.get is a string and returns an error
Findbutt.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 2)    

root2.mainloop()        

#Here is the funtion i am trying to use:
def search(title):
    y = title.get("Year")
    fame = Label (root, text = "Year")
    fame.grid(root,row = 3, column = 0)
    foo = Label (root, text = y)
    foo.grid(root, row = 3, column = 1)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do with the code  _y = title.get("Year")_  ?

Comment: show your dictionaries. Probably you need one dictionary with all books and something like this `one_dictionary_with_all_books[title].get('Year')`

Comment: I am trying to get the year from the dictionary that is inputted in the Entry.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting? Can you put `print(title)` as the first line of your `search` function and show us the output?

Comment: `titlein.get()` returns a `str` you are then doing `title.get("Year")` are you mistaking `title` for a `dict`?